# Setting Optimization flags in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, assembly

How do you set optimization/debugging flags in Eclipse CDT, set up uses GNU tool-chain  ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the kind of project you set up. Is it a makefile project?

You can also use the CFLAGS CXXFLAGS environment variables.

I will suggest you to use cmake and then generate the Eclipse CDT project with 
CMake -G "Eclipse CDT4 Makefile"

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to Eclipse

Comment: You mean in Eclipse's Run Configuration > Environment > New > Name: CFLAGS, Value: -0  ?? Right ?

Comment: Right click on the project name -> Properties -> C/C Make Project -> Environment

Answer (score 7):

You can also go to Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings. Click on the triangle next to your compiler to see the drop down menu -> click on Optimization. On the right hand side next to Optimization Level choose from the drop down menu your desired level. (Be aware though that once you set optimization level up from None (-O0) you will experience issues when debugging... values not available, skipping of breakpoints etc.)
Hope this helps!